# What is the "a" in "List a" in the length example?

Tags: polymorphism, elm

I'm wondering where I can find information about the "`a`" used in the [Length example](http://elm-lang.org/examples/length). It seems to be a type of some kind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[1,2,3]` is a `List Int`, functions that could only work with a Lists of Ints would have to have `List Int` in their type signature. `["a", "b"]` is a `List String`, functions that could only work with a Lists of Strings would have to have `List String` in their type signature. A function that works with a list of any type (for example `List.length`) can have a generic type signature (like `List a` or `List b`). The meaning of `a` is only relevant within the type signature. For example a function with a type of `List a -> a`, when given a `List Int` would return an `Int`. When given a `List String` it would return a `String`.

Take for example the [`map`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/List#map) function which has a signature of `(a -> b) -> List a -> List b`. It says that given a function that takes an `a` and returns a `b`, and a `List a`, it will return a `List b`.

Given a function that takes a `String` and returns an `Int`, and a `List String`, `map` will return a `List Int`.

```elm
List.map String.length ["a", "aa", "aaa"]
-- [1, 2, 3] : List Int
```

Given a function that takes an `Int` and returns a `String`, and a `List Int`, `map` will return a `List String`.

```elm
List.map (\n -> String.repeat n "a") [1, 2, 3]
-- ["a", "aa", "aaa"] : List String
```

Answer (score 2):

`a` is a type variable.

This means that the type `List` is polymorphic (generic), i.e. `a` can be substituted by any type (`Int`, `String`, ...). The function `length` is polymorphic too. For example, `length [1, 2, 3]` will return `3`, `length ["word1", "word2"]` will return `2`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, I don't see the type polymorphism you are referring to. Considering your example, length [1,2,3] or length ["word1", "word2"], for each call it receives a List as input, and outputs an integer.

Comment: But `a` is undefined right ? If I replace `a` with `b` or `c` or pretty much anything, it'll also work. It's confusing !

Comment: @doobdargent There is a simple rule to distinguish type variables from types (`List Int` vs `List a`): type names must begin with an uppercase letter, type variable names must start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: @MihaiCicu It cannot receive `List`, because `List` is not a type (it is a type constructor actually, but this is a more complicated thing). I.e. you cannot declare a function of type `List -> Int` (it will not compile).

Comment: with robertjlooby's explanation, now I understand what u meant. thanks anyway