# What does comparable mean in Elm?

Tags: elm

I'm having trouble understanding what exactly a `comparable` is in Elm. Elm seems as confused as I am.

On the REPL:

```
> f1 = (<)
<function> : comparable -> comparable -> Bool
```

So `f1` accepts comparables.

```
> "a"
"a" : String
> f1 "a" "b"
True : Bool
```

So it seems `String` is comparable.

```
> f2 = (<) 1
<function> : comparable -> Bool
```

So `f2` accepts a comparable.

```
> f2 "a"
As I infer the type of values flowing through your program, I see a conflict
between these two types:

    comparable

    String
```

So `String` **is** and **is not** comparable?
Why is the type of `f2` not `number -> Bool`? What other comparables can `f2` accept?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normally when you see a type variable in a type in Elm, this variable is unconstrained. When you then supply something of a specific type, the variable gets replaced by that specific type:

```
-- says you have a function:
foo : a -> a -> a -> Int
-- then once you give an value with an actual type to foo, all occurences of `a` are replaced by that type:
value : Float
foo value : Float -> Float -> Int
```

`comparable` is a type variable with a built-in special meaning. That meaning is that it will only match against "comparable" types, like `Int`, `String` and a few others. But otherwise it should behave the same. So I think there is a little bug in the type system, given that you get:

```
> f2 "a"
As I infer the type of values flowing through your program, I see a conflict
between these two types:

    comparable

    String
```

If the bug weren't there, you would get:

```
> f2 "a"
As I infer the type of values flowing through your program, I see a conflict
between these two types:

    Int

    String
```

EDIT: I opened an [issue](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/1013) for this bug

Comment: For future reference, this bug was fixed in late 2015. `comparable` can be found here: https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Basics#compare

Answer (score 6):

> Compare any two comparable values. Comparable values include `String`, `Char`, `Int`, `Float`, `Time`, or a `list` or `tuple` **containing comparable values**. These are also the only values that work as Dict keys or Set members.

taken from the elm docs [here](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Basics#compare).

**In older Elm versions:**

> Comparable types includes `numbers`, `characters`, `strings`,~~
> `lists of comparable things`, and `tuples of comparable things`. Note that
> tuples with 7 or more elements are not comparable; why are your tuples
> so big?

This means that:

```
[(1,"string"), (2, "another string")] : List (Int, String) -- is comparable
```

But having

```
(1, "string",  True)` : (Int, String, Bool) -- or...

[(1,True), (2, False)] : List (Int, Bool ) -- are ***not comparable yet***.
```

This issue is discussed [here](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/1008)

Note: Usually people encounter problems with the `comparable` type when they try to use a *union type* as a **Key** in a ***Dict***.

**Tags and Constructors of union types are not comparable**. ***So the following doesn't even compile.***

```
type SomeUnion = One | Two | Three
Dict.fromList [ (One, "one related"), (Two, "two related") ] : Dict SomeUnion String
```

Usually when you try to do this, there is a better approach to your data structure. But until this gets decided - an [AllDict](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/eeue56/elm-all-dict/2.0.1/AllDict#AllDict) can be used.

Comment: It seems you read the title of my question but not the full content. My confusion at the time of the question was because there was a bug in the compiler. The answer selected as correct references the bug. https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/1013

Comment: @z5h yes, you are right in that regard. Still, i think my answer is relevant, because this question is the first thing that pops up in Google - once a person new to elm tries to understand ***what `comparable` means***.

My answer is for them - because I lost 20 minutes myself  - to understand **what exactly this comparable is** -  i was surprised to find that `Bools` are not considered comparable for example. The selected answer explains: "Int, String and a few others" - not very specific. This is why i included the elm-docs fragment.

Comment: This answer is outdated. That quote and link point to an old version of elm-core (new one here: https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Basics#compare) and Elm can no longer have Tuples with more than two members.

Comment: @Charlie  `Elm can no longer have Tuples with more than two members` - what do you mean by this? Elm accepts `(1,2,3)`. it does not accept `(1,2,3,4)` and it forces you to use a named record - which is a good idea. You can still go around it by using `((1,2,3,), 4 )` but using a record is much better for everybody involved because it does not increase cognitive load with remembering what value you wanted in place 3 and 4. Ill update the answer.

Comment: Good catch! I meant "Elm can no longer have Tuples with more than _three_ members"

Answer (score 3):

I think this question can be related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31268051/what-is-the-a-in-list-a-in-the-length-example). `Int` and `String` are both `comparable` in the sense that strings can be compared to strings and ints can be compared to ints. A function that can take any two comparables would have a signature `comparable -> comparable -> ...` but within any one evaluation of the function both of the comparables must be of the same type.

I believe the reason `f2` is confusing above is that `1` is a `number` instead of a concrete type (which seems to stop the compiler from recognizing that the comparable must be of a certain type, probably should be fixed). If you were to do:

```
i = 4 // 2
f1 = (<) i   -- type Int -> Bool
f2 = (<) "a" -- type String -> Bool
```

you would see it actually *does* collapse `comparable` to the correct type when it can.