# Strange compiler error in Elm

Tags: types, elm

Given the code such as (imports are stripped for brevity):

```
fn: List a -> List a -> Bool
fn x y =
  x < y

main =
  text (toString(fn [1,1] [1,2]))
```

I got quite a strange error:

```
The type annotation for `fn` does not match its definition.

15| fn: List a -> List a -> Bool
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The type annotation is saying:

    List a -> List a -> Bool

But I am inferring that the definition has this type:

    List a -> List a -> Bool
```

Without the type annotation or with type annotation but using `==` instead of `<` everything works OK. Is this a bug in elm compiler or am I doing something wrong?

I used online editor at http://elm-lang.org/try

Comment: It seems you need to mark `a` as `comparable`. This type declaration typechecks `fn: List comparable -> List comparable -> Bool`. I think it is all because you can compare list of comparable items. But it is just a speculation since I'm new to elm. :)

Comment: Huh, that really solves it :) But.. what does the comparable actually do? I saw this keyword already but I thought that in this context, this is just a placeholder to denote the variable which is as good as `a` which I used.

Comment: "what does the comparable actually do" I don't know. Some sort of a built-in type constrain I guess. I'm new to elm that's why I've posted it as a comment waiting for someone who knows more :)

Comment: Ok, so it seems 'comparable' really is a type constraint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31885622/what-does-comparable-mean-in-elm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with the compiler, it's been reported [here](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/1422). It looks like y'all have already figured out what `comparable` does based on the comments but for those who prefer to skip to the answers:

There are a couple of "magic" type variables that can be used in type annotations to constrain the types of things that can be passed in. They are:

- `comparable` (`Int`, `Float`, `Char`, `String`, and `List`s and n-tuples of any of those): anything that operators like `(<)` will accept, as you've discovered
- `appendable` (`String`, `List`, `Text`): anything that the `(++)` operator will accept
- `number` (`Float`, `Int`): anything that operators like `(+)` and `(-)` will accept