# Type constraints in Elm

Tags: types, polymorphism, typeclass, elm

According to [What does comparable mean in Elm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31885622/what-does-comparable-mean-in-elm) `comparable` is built-in type constraint that can be used to limit type variables to those built-in types that are, well, comparable. The following questions comes to mind (and are not so easy to find out):

- what are the other type constraints that currently exists in Elm? Is there a list somewhere?
- Is there a way how I can create my own type constraints? I presume that the answer is no, since Elm does not have any mechanism such as Haskell Typeclasses right now?
- If the above is true (no custom type constraints), that does mean that the polymorphism is quite limited in Elm, doesn't it? For example, it seems that the following is not achievable right now: I want to create a function `f` that accepts List of elements (of a same but uncertain type) each of which can be used as an argument to some function `g` (i.e. `f` accepts `List a` and moreover `inst` being of type `a` implies that `g(inst)` makes sense)

Comment: Have you seen [these](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/38) [two](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/1039) issues regarding type classes?

Comment: Yes, I saw both these. OTOH, I saw there is a concept such as `comparable`, so I wasn't sure, what's the status of this in Elm.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Besides `comparable` (ints, floats, chars, strings, lists, and tuples) there are also `appendable` (strings, text, and lists) and `number` (ints and floats). I have not seen an authoritative list (outside of the compiler source).

There is no way to define similar typeclasses of your own.

Yes, this limits what functions you can write. No one has convinced Evan that this limit is a problem.

Comment: Thank you, that's pretty clear now. Also, looking at all the stuff that Haskell developers have built to make typeclasses powerful enough (and still, many rant about it!), I understand that Evan is reluctant about this :)

Answer (score 1):

From Elm's official guide:

> The full list of constrained type variables is:
>
> - `number` permits `Int` and `Float`
> - `appendable` permits `String` and `List a`
> - `comparable` permits `Int`, `Float`, `Char`, `String`, and lists/tuples of comparable values
> - `compappend` permits `String` and `List comparable`

[Elm's Guide > Reading Types > Constrained Type Variables](https://guide.elm-lang.org/types/reading_types.html)