# In Elm, how to use comparable type in a tagged unions types?

Tags: elm

I can define a tagged unions type like that:

```
type Msg
  = Sort (Product -> Float)
```

But I cannot define it like:

```
type Msg
  = Sort (Product -> comparable)
```

The error says:

Type `Msg` must declare its use of type variable comparable...

But comparable is a pre-defined type variable, right?

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried following elm compiler instructions?  
You probably need to change the declaration like this:
`type Msg comparable = ...`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This question feels a little like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem#answer-66378). I'd like to offer a different way of thinking about passing sorting functions around in your message (with the caveat that I'm not familiar with your codebase, only the examples you've given in your question).

Adding a type parameter to `Msg` does seem a bit messy so let's take a step back. Sorting involves comparing two of the same types in a certain way and returning whether the first value is less than, equal to, or greater than the second. Elm already has an [`Order`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Basics#Order) type using for comparing things which has the type constructors LT, EQ, and GT (for Less Than, EQual, and Greater Than).

Let's refactor your `Msg` into the following:

```elm
type Msg
    = Sort (Product -> Product -> Order)
```

Now we don't have to add a type parameter to `Msg`. But how, then, do we specify which field of `Product` to sort by? We can use currying for that. Here's how:

Let's define another function called `comparing` which takes a function as its first argument and two other arguments of the same type, and return an `Order` value:

```elm
comparing : (a -> comparable) -> a -> a -> Order
comparing f x y =
    compare (f x) (f y)
```

Notice the first argument is a function that looks similar to what your example was trying to attempt in the `(Product -> comparable)` argument of the `Sort` constructor. That's no coincidence. Now, by using currying, we can partially apply the `comparing` function with a record field getter, like `.name` or `.price`. To amend your example, the `onClick` handler could look like this:

```elm
onClick (Sort (comparing .name))
```

If you go this route, there will be more refactoring. Now that you have this comparison function, how do you use it in your `update` function? Let's assume your `Model` has a field called `products` which is of type `List Product`. In that case, we can just use the [`List.sortWith`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/List#sortWith) function to sort our list. Your update case for the `Sort` `Msg` would look something like this:

```elm
case msg of
    Sort comparer ->
        { model | products = List.sortWith comparer model.products } ! []
```

---

A few closing thoughts and other notes:

This business about a [`comparing`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=comparing) function comes straight from Haskell where it fulfills the same need.

Rather than defining the `Sort` constructor as above, I would probably abstract it out a little more since it is such a common idiom. You could define an alias for a generalized function like this, then redefine `Msg` as shown here:

```elm
type alias Comparer a =
    a -> a -> Order

type Msg
    = Sort (Comparer Product)
```

And to take it one step further just to illustrate how this all connects, the following two type annotations for `comparing` are identical:

```elm
-- this is the original example from up above
comparing : (a -> comparable) -> a -> a -> Order

-- this example substitutues the `Comparer a` alias, which may help further 
-- your understanding of how it all ties together
comparing : (a -> comparable) -> Comparer a
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I want to achieve but didn't know how to do. I learned a lot with the info you put here. Sorry to make it feel like a XY problem. When I face the problem with the parameterized union type, I feel like it's more important than the original problem I was trying to solve (passing sort function), so I was eager to an answer for that first. But you're right, it seems the problem is better explained with the whole picture.

Comment: Before I saw your answer, I also tried to solve the problem by defining separate message types: "type Msg = SortFloat (Product -> Float) | SortString (Product -> String)", then "onClick (SortFloat .price)" and "onClick (SortString .name)". It's working, but it's not a good solution since we are repeating the same logic just to handle 2 different types. Just want to share what I have tried, but your answer is definitely the right way to go

Comment: Or, inspired by your currying thought, we could call List.sortBy with the 1st parameter at the view level, so no need to handle any type variable at the Msg level, "type Msg = Sort (List Product -> List Product)", then "onClick (Sort (List.sortBy .name))" and "onClick (Sort (List.sortBy .price))", update would be "case msg of Sort f -> { model | products = f model.products }". The power of currying!

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is saying that `comparable` is an unbound variable type. You need to either fully specify it on the right hand side (e.g. `Product -> Int`) or specify you would like it to be polymorphic on the left hand side. Something like this:

`type Msg a = Sort (Product -> a)`

The question you ask about `comparable` is answered here: [What does comparable mean in Elm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31885622/what-does-comparable-mean-in-elm)

Comment: Thanks. But if I specify it on the left, then I have to specify a real type when I use Msg in a view, like "view : Model -> Html (Msg Float)", which defeat the purpose to define a type variable in the first place (I want to be able to Sort on different fields, like "onClick (Sort .price)" or "onClick (Sort .name)", which would be in the same view but with different field type ). So is it possible to do this?

Comment: It sounds like you need your Model to be polymorphic as well.

`Model a = { data : List a }`